# Disable change detection propagation to parent

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

In my header component I show current time and update it every second. Since changing time
does not influence any other component, I don't want Angular to run change detection every second for the whole graph of components. Each second, it seems that Angular runs change detection not only on parent component but also on components that are not on the path from header component to root component (sidenav and maincontent).

By having getter `{{runChangeDetection}}` in 3 other components' templates (sidenav, maincontent and mainview) I see in dev tools that every second these 7 rows are being printed:

- CD HeaderComponent
- CD MainContentComponent
- CD SideTreeComponent
- CD MAIN VIEW
- CD MainContentComponent
- CD SideTreeComponent
- CD MAIN VIEW

I tried with onpush strategy with calling `detectChanges()` every second. Also with and without `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()`.

What am I doing wrong? How to disable whole tree change detection run and path from the root to header component change detection.

header.ts:

```ts
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  get runChangeDetection() {
    console.log('CD HeaderComponent');
    return true;
  }
  public time :Date = new Date()
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
    this.cdr.detach()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date()
      this.cdr.detectChanges()
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

header.html:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="time">{{time | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
</mat-toolbar>
{{runChangeDetection}}
```

Comment: I believe you can solve this by implementing the OnPush strategy in all the components you don't want to be automatic checked by Angular. Or you can use the .detach() method in the same components (without implementing the OnPush strategy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Re-running of change detection is not triggered by detectChanges(), but by setInterval method since this method is patched by Zone.

You can check by deleting the line with detectChanges() and see that change detection re-runs even though no value is changed.

Solution that worked for me is:

```js
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.time = new Date()
        this.cdr.detectChanges()
      }, 1000)
    })
```

Comment: I was working with Plotly and this helped bring down change detection considerably